# Windows Mobile Click Handler doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, event-handling, menu, menuitem

I have an urgent problem..I am developing a windows mobile 6.0 application and the menu item key (which I putted on left side to serve as a back button) only fires when I double click it or after several one clicks..but the items on the right side which in a menu works fine..

I see on the screen that it is clicked(phone vibrates) but it does not fall into the clickitem action.

going crazy someone helps please!!

it does not hit the `actionMenuItem_Click_1()` method at all if I dont double click

```
this.actionMenuItem.Text = "select";
this.actionMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.actionMenuItem_Click_1);

private void actionMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (actionMenuItem.Text == "Back")
    {
        if (dialogStack.Count > 0)
        {
            navigateBack();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll need to post some code..

Comment: what does "navigateBack" do?  You should also be using proper casing for method names - it's a good habit for readability.

Comment: -1 For marking your problem as urgent in subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers, I solved it..I am doing some weird stuff in onpaint() that is interfering..

Answer (score 3):

First of all - and this is very, very important - never, ever mark a question as urgent. Everyone who asks a question is looking for an answer here and they typically want or need the answer in a short period of time.  Marking yours as urgent seems to say that you feel that your question is more important than every other question or that for some reason you should get some sort of priority treatment.  My reaction when I see "urgent" is to ignore the question completely.

All answers here are given by volunteers for free.  If you have some "urgent" issue that you need an immediate answer to, go pay someone to solve it where they have a contractual obligation to meet your schedule.  Otherwise just ask your question.

Second, this is not a good question.  The title needs to be a **question**.  "URGENT" is not a question.  You' also given us a very generalized behavior description, but we see absolutely no code.  We don't see any description of what you've done to try to fix it.  Not only are you asking us to give your question priority, you're also asking us to read your mind and divine the behaviors and code that only you see.  We don't even know what kind of device this is or whenther it's WinMo Standard or Professional.

So let me shake shaking my magic 8-ball and see what it says about your issue given what we know...it says that your menu click handler calls some long-running method and is therefore interfering with subsequent clicks.

Comment: You should have read the FAQ before posting the question in the first place and this would have never happened.

Comment: I'm not being hostile, I'm simply informing you.  My apology for attempting to help you get an answer to your question.

Comment: you are right..but when you have less than hour to solve it, no time..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging? what are the values of actionMenuItem.Text and dialogStack.Count when you step trough your code using the debugger?

Comment: Thanks for answers, ok I removed everything from that method and put some dummy code..still I can hit the method only after several clicks.

I use a timer and a thread in that form..but I tried by removing the thread, nothing changed

Comment: So you will enter actionMenuItem_Click_1 only after a few clicks or not? (Debugging question remains unanswered)